# Attach interactive console to embedded python script

Tags: c++, windows, python-2.7

I have a Python Script that I run from a C++ GUI Application.
I want to get the output of that Script into a Python Console and have the ability to manipulate them before calling another Python Function from C++.

My Question: Is that possible by just redirection stdin & stdout to Files?
Is there a better way using pure python?

Please note that I don´t want to spawn the console from the C++ Programm but from outside the C++ Programm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to adapt the approach in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241234/#4247395) to your needs. The example it links to uses UDP sockets for transferring commands to/from the interactive interpreter, but you could easily change that to pull data from `stdin` (or wherever) instead.

The key thing to take away from the example is the use of the builtin `InteractiveConsole`'s `push()` method to determine whether the input is:

1. Well-formed Python snippet that may be evaluated as-is
2. A syntactically invalid snippet, or
3. A snippet that may *become* valid, but more input is needed