# Access standard output of a sub process in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

How can I access the stdout of child processes prior to sending them to main process? I am using multiprocessing.Pool module to generate child process pools.

Comment: maybe this could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7714868/python-multiprocessing-how-can-i-reliably-redirect-stdout-from-a-child-process

Comment: @Udy the question you reference seems like a windows specific stdout redirection issue. Also, they're trying to redirect the stdout to a file. I on the other hand want to just modify the child process's stdout.

Comment: true.  but this will defantly help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227808/how-can-i-send-python-multiprocessing-process-output-to-a-tkinter-gui

Answer (score 9):

The main process and the children all share the same standard input and standard output file descriptors. They have no control over what the other writes to them. The only thing you can do is replace `stdin` and `stdout` in the children with something else that the main process can control. As an example you could subclass a dummy file object like [`StringIO`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) and redirect the data that the children write to this object to the parent via a [`Queue`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=queue#multiprocessing.Queue):

```
import sys
from multiprocessing import Queue, Pool, current_process
from StringIO import StringIO

class MyStringIO(StringIO):
    def __init__(self, queue, *args, **kwargs):
        StringIO.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.queue = queue
    def flush(self):
        self.queue.put((current_process().name, self.getvalue()))
        self.truncate(0)

def initializer(queue):
     sys.stderr = sys.stdout = MyStringIO(queue)

def task(num):
     print num
     sys.stdout.flush()
     return num ** 2

q = Queue()
pool = Pool(3, initializer, [q])

for _ in pool.map(task, range(5)):
    proc, out = q.get()
    print proc, "got", out
```

This should print something like this:

```
PoolWorker-1 got 0
PoolWorker-1 got 3
PoolWorker-1 got 4
PoolWorker-2 got 1
PoolWorker-3 got 2
```

Don't forget to call `sys.{stdout,stderr}.flush()` at the end of `task` otherwise, nothing will be written to the queue.

Comment: the children's output is redirected to the `MyStringIO` object which then sends the data to the main process via the queue. The main process then does all the processing it needs and outputs it to `sys.stdout` (which, as I explain in my updated answer, is shared by all processes attached to the terminal)