# Run multiple threads simultaneously but print one by one python?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

As you might have an idea what I am talking about. So let me explain it more clearly.

For ex:- I have four threads which runs simulatenoulsy, Something like that.

```
th1 = threading.Thread(target=connCheck,  args= (newurl, schemess, 21))
th2 = threading.Thread(target=connCheck,  args=( newurl, schemess, 22))
th3 = threading.Thread(target=connCheck,  args= (newurl, schemess,80))
th4 = threading.Thread(target=connCheck,  args=(newurl, schemess,8080))
```

(this is the scanner for scanning ports of port number 21, 22, 80, 8080.)

And I run these threads like this:-

```
th1.start()
th2.start()
th3.start()
th4.start()
th4.join()
```

NOTE:- connCheck is a function to tell that what ports are open.

So in my terminal it shows that both ports are open **BUT** in a very bad manner. Sometimes it prints like this

```
List of port open:-

[+]21 [+]22 [+]80
[+]8080
```

And somethimes it prints like this:-

```
List of port open:-

[+]21 
[+]22 [+]80
[+]8080
```

And sometimes it prints some other way.

So What I want them to print in a Single good mannner like Line wise. But the most important thing to remember is I want to run all the above threads simultaneously so that it would not affect the speed of scan.

So I am come here to ask you. So please any one guide me in here.

Thanks

[EDIT]:- Here is the conncheck function:-

```
try: 

        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.settimeout(3)

        result = sock.connect_ex((ip, port))

        newip = schemess+ip+slash

        if port == 21:
            if result == 0:

                print "\t [+]" + str(port)
                ftpurls.append(newip)
                dicta(newip, port)


        else:
            if result == 0:


                    print '\t' + str(port)+ '\n'

                    dicta(newip, port)                      


        sock.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print str(e) + '\n'
```

Please ignore the dicta function.

Comment: Can you post your connCheck function?

Comment: Use a queue. Have the only one thread (the main one) print the items from the queue.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44489010) - that is the more complicated case with `multiprocessing` but the first example (main process/thread dealing with the output) will work well in a multi-threading scenario, too. You can go even simpler than that by sharing some structure instead of returning and collecting the results as multi-threading supports shared memory.

Comment: You can use `ThreadPoolExecutor` like this `with ThreadPoolExecutor() as t:
    for data in t.map(connCheck, repeat(newurl), repeat(newurl), list_port,):
        ...`

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do it, using locks and another one is using `logging` module. I have been writing multithreading code using `threading.Lock()`, but I recently found out that `logging` is much more easier to use.

```
lock = threading.Lock()
with lock:
     print("...")
```

`with lock` will call `lock.acquire()` on enter, and on exit, it will call `lock.release()`. Or you can manually call those. But make sure to `release` it after you've acquired or you would be facing deadlocks.

The other easier way is to use `logging` as I mentioned. `logging` library is thread-safe, meaning any threads can use the functions at the same time. Using this module also allows you to write logs to the logfiles.

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(format='%(message)s')
logging.info("...")
```