# Cannot Pool.map() function because of UnpickleableError?

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, multiprocessing

So I am trying to multi process function F. Which is accessed by a button press with tkinter.

```
def f(x):
    global doom,results,info
    doom = doom + 1
    if check(x) == True:
        results.add(x)
        info.append(get_column_number(x))
    j.step(1)
    texx = "1/"+doom
    s.configure(text=texx)
    root.update()
```

The function is called within a function like so:

```
def dojob():
    index = ['URLS'...]
    pool = Pool(processes=4)
    s.configure(text="Shifting Workload to cores..")
    root.update()     
    pool.map(f, index)
```

The button is inside root window.

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 808, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 761, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 342, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
UnpickleableError: Cannot pickle <type 'tkapp'> objects
```

I do not even know what a pickle does? Help?

Here is the  complete code:

```
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *
from tkMessageBox import showinfo
from multiprocessing import Pool
import random
emails = set()
import urllib2
import urllib2 as urllib
########

CONSTANT_PAGECOUNT = 20

######
def f(x):
    global doom,emails,info
    doom = doom + 1
    if check(x) == True:
        print "",
        emails.add(x)
        info.append(get_column_number(x))
    j.step(1)
    texx = "Sk1nn1n "+str(doom)+'/'+str(CONSTANT_PAGECOUNT)+""
    s.configure(text=texx)
    root.update()
    return 0
def f(x):
    print ""
def showFile(site,info):
    top = Toplevel()
    top.title('Sites')
    x = Text(top)
    x.pack()
    i=0
    for site_url in site:

        x.insert(END,site_url)
        i=i+1

def get_column_number(url):
    return True

def check(url):
    return True

def getgoogleurl(search,siteurl=False,startr=0):
    if siteurl==False:
        return 'http://www.google.com/search?q='+urllib2.quote(search)+'&start='+str(startr)+'&oq='+urllib2.quote(search)
    else:
        return 'http://www.google.com/search?q=site:'+urllib2.quote(siteurl)+'%20'+urllib2.quote(search)+'&oq=site:'+urllib2.quote(siteurl)+'%20'+urllib2.quote(search)

def getgooglelinks(search,siteurl=False,startr=0):
   #google returns 403 without user agent
   headers = {'User-agent':'Mozilla/11.0'}
   req = urllib2.Request(getgoogleurl(search,siteurl,startr),None,headers)
   site = urllib2.urlopen(req)
   data = site.read()
   site.close()

   #no beatifulsoup because google html is generated with javascript
   start = data.find('<div id="res">')
   end = data.find('<div id="foot">')
   if data[start:end]=='':
      #error, no links to find
      return False
   else:
      links =[]
      data = data[start:end]
      start = 0
      end = 0        
      while start>-1 and end>-1:
          #get only results of the provided site
          if siteurl==False:
            start = data.find('<a href="/url?q=')
          else:
            start = data.find('<a href="/url?q='+str(siteurl))
          data = data[start+len('<a href="/url?q='):]
          end = data.find('&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=')
          if start>-1 and end>-1: 
              link =  urllib2.unquote(data[0:end])
              data = data[end:len(data)]
              if link.find('http')==0:
                  links.append(link)
      return links

def rip(results=15,accuracy=16):
    global e
    keyword = ''+str(e.get())
    if keyword.strip()=="":
        s.configure(text="Please enter a keyword")
        root.update()
        return 0
    linklist = []
    counter = 0
    doom = 0
    while counter < results:
        links = getgooglelinks(keyword,startr=counter)
        for link in links:
            if len(linklist) > CONSTANT_PAGECOUNT:
                s.configure(text="Proccessing..")
                root.update()
                return linklist
            else:
                doom = doom + 1
                linklist.append(link)
                texx = str(doom)+"/"+str(CONSTANT_PAGECOUNT)
                s.configure(text=texx)
                root.update()
        root.update()
        counter = counter+accuracy
    return linklist
def flip():
    global e
    emails = set()
    info = []
    keyword = ''+str(e.get())
    if keyword.strip()=="":
        s.configure(text="Please enter a keyword")
        root.update()
        return 0
    s.configure(text="Generating index..")
    root.update()
    doom = -1
    index = rip(CONSTANT_PAGECOUNT,10)
    if 1:
        try:
            pool = Pool(processes=4)
            #s.configure(text="Shifting Workload to cores..")
            #root.update()     
            pool.map(f, index)
            pool.close()
        except:
            print "The errors there.."
    j.config(value=CONSTANT_PAGECOUNT)
    if len(emails) > 0:
        filepath='relavant_list_'+str(random.randint(1,9999))+'.emList.txt'
        #print len(emails),
        #print "emails found."
        ggg = open(filepath,'a+')
        for x in emails:
            ggg.write(x+"\n")
        showinfo(
            str(len(emails))+" key word related sites found!",
            " sites are saved in "+str(filepath)
        )
        showFile(emails,info)
        s.configure(text=filepath)
    else:
        s.configure(text='No related sites found : (')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ### CONSTANTS
    version = '1.0'
    ### END CONSTANTS
    root = Tk()
    root.title('Program v'+version)
    s = Style()
    s.theme_use('default')
    #print s.theme_names()
    s.configure("black.Horizontal.TProgressbar", foreground='blue', background='blue')
    j = Progressbar(root, style="black.Horizontal.TProgressbar", orient="vertical", length=200, mode="determinate", maximum=CONSTANT_PAGECOUNT, value=0)
    j.pack(side='right',fill='y')
    f = Frame(root)
    x = Frame(f)
    e = Entry(x,width=51)
    s = Label(x,width=50,anchor='center',text='Waiting for task..')
    Button(f,text='Generate List!',width=50,command=flip).pack(fill='both',expand=True)
    s.pack(side='bottom',fill='y',expand=True)
    e.pack(side='top',fill='both',expand=True)
    x.pack(side='top',fill='y',expand=True)
    f.pack(side='left',expand=True,fill="both")
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are leaking a tkinter object. Most likely because you are trying to update the interface from another process with the last line of `f()`

**Update based on code**

You have a name collision between your function `f()` and a variable `f` in your `__main__` which gets assigned to your main window and causes the tkapp pickle error. Rename the function to def `myfunc()` or something. Also need to call pool.join() after pool.close()

Comment: So how could I fix this, while still letting the user know the progress?

Comment: You can only access the UI from the original process. Can implement message passing scheme to allow subprocesses to tell the main process to update the UI. It isn't clear what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: So I made F completely blank, except for a print "", and I got the same error.

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227808/how-can-i-send-python-multiprocessing-process-output-to-a-tkinter-gui

Comment: I tried your answer and it worked. But now I get this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21187525/multiprocessing-just-freezes-no-error-given