# Multiprocessing in class isn't using full cpu range

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, multiprocessing

I have a Program which, on start, opens a GUI which allows the user to select a raw  file which then is getting read in and a function is called to calculate some stuff which is then getting saved in a pickle file.

Depending on the size of the file this might take up to 12 or more hours. (heavy calculations)
So my approach was to allow the Program to run the calculations in different processes with the multiprocessing module. But it seems like I am not using the full range of the CPU. When I start the first process the CPU utilization goes from like 4-5% up to around 20% but when I start the second process it stays at around 20%

The code is to big to post it here so im trying to explain it as good as possible

```
class main():
    def __init__(self,master):
            self.processes= {'1': 0, '2' :0, '3' :0,'4':0,'5':0,'6':0}
            self.master = master
            self.master.title("Framework")
            self.master.minsize(1450, 650)
            self.master.maxsize(1450,650)
            style = ttk.Style()
            style.theme_use('clam')
            style.configure('Custom.TButton',background='#94FDFA')
            self.Box4 = Entry(self.master)
            self.text = Text(self.master)
            self.scroll = Scrollbar(self.master, command=self.text.yview)
            self.text.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scroll.set)
            self.text.tag_configure('bold_italics', font=('Verdana', 12, 'bold', 'italic'))
            self.text.place( x = 450, y =80,bordermode="inside", width=300,height=250)
            self.scroll.place(x=750,y=80, height= 250)

            self.text2 = Text(self.master)
            self.scroll2 = Scrollbar(self.master, command=self.text.yview)
            self.text2.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scroll2.set)
            self.text2.tag_configure('bold_italics', font=('Verdana', 12, 'bold', 'italic'))
            self.text2.place( x = 775, y =80,bordermode="inside", width=300,height=250)
            self.scroll2.place(x=1075,y=80, height= 250)            

            self.text3 = Text(self.master)
            self.scroll3 = Scrollbar(self.master, command=self.text.yview)
            self.text3.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scroll3.set)
            self.text3.tag_configure('bold_italics', font=('Verdana', 12, 'bold', 'italic'))
            self.text3.place( x = 1100, y =80,bordermode="inside", width=300,height=250)
            self.scroll3.place(x=1400,y=80, height= 250)     

            self.text4 = Text(self.master)
            self.scroll4 = Scrollbar(self.master, command=self.text.yview)
            self.text4.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scroll4.set)
            self.text4.tag_configure('bold_italics', font=('Verdana', 12, 'bold', 'italic'))
            self.text4.place( x = 450, y =370,bordermode="inside", width=300,height=250)
            self.scroll4.place(x=750,y=370, height= 250)

            self.text5 = Text(self.master)
            self.scroll5 = Scrollbar(self.master, command=self.text.yview)
            self.text5.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scroll5.set)
            self.text5.tag_configure('bold_italics', font=('Verdana', 12, 'bold', 'italic'))
            self.text5.place( x = 775, y =370,bordermode="inside", width=300,height=250)
            self.scroll5.place(x=1075,y=370, height= 250)            

            self.text6 = Text(self.master)
            self.scroll6 = Scrollbar(self.master, command=self.text.yview)
            self.text6.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scroll6.set)
            self.text6.tag_configure('bold_italics', font=('Verdana', 12, 'bold', 'italic'))
            self.text6.place( x = 1100, y =370,bordermode="inside", width=300,height=250)
            self.scroll6.place(x=1400,y=370, height= 250)  
            self.Box4.place( x = 10, y = 10,bordermode="inside", width=820,height=35)
            self.b1 = ttk.Button(self.master,text = "Folder", command=self.select_folder)
            self.b1.place(x=850, y=10)   
            self.b2 = ttk.Button(self.master, text="run", command=self.go)
            self.b2.place(x=20, y=600)
            self.master.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (950, 400, 20, 20))


    def update(self, tid):
        try:
            if tid == self.processes['2']:
                self.text.insert(END, (self.text1 + '\n'))
                self.text.see("end")
        except IndexError:
            return
        except AttributeError:
            return                
        try:
            if tid == self.processes['1']:
                self.text2.insert(END, (self.text1 + '\n'))
                self.text2.see("end")        
        except IndexError:
            return
        except AttributeError:
            return
        try:
            if tid == self.processes['3']:
                self.text3.insert(END, (self.text1 + '\n'))
                self.text3.see("end")
        except IndexError:
            return
        except AttributeError:
            return                
        try:
            if tid == self.processes['4']:
                self.text4.insert(END, (self.text1 + '\n'))
                self.text4.see("end")        
        except IndexError:
            return
        except AttributeError:
            return
        try:
            if tid == self.processes['5']:
                self.text5.insert(END, (self.text1 + '\n'))
                self.text5.see("end")
        except IndexError:
            return
        except AttributeError:
            return                
        try:
            if tid == self.processes['6']:
                self.text6.insert(END, (self.text1 + '\n'))
                self.text6.see("end")        
        except IndexError:
            return
        except AttributeError:
            return       

    def select_folder(self):
        mas = tk.Toplevel()
        mas.withdraw()
        dir_path = filedialog.askdirectory()
        self.Box4.insert(0,str(dir_path))
        self.dir_path = dir_path          

    def go(self):
        Thread(target = self.spawn).start()

    def spawn(self):
                while True:
                    if self.processes['1'] == 0:
                        proc = 1
                        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.run(proc))
                        p.start()
                        p.join()                        
                        break
                    if self.processes['2'] == 0:
                        proc = 2
                        p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.run(proc))
                        p2.start()
                        p2.join()  
                        break
                    if self.processes['3'] == 0:
                        proc = 3
                        p3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.run(proc))
                        p3.start()
                        p3.join() 
                        break
                    if self.processes['4'] == 0:
                        proc = 4
                        p4 = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.run(proc))
                        p4.start()
                        p4.join() 
                        break
                    if self.processes['5'] == 0:
                        proc = 5
                        p5 = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.run(proc))
                        p5.start()
                        p5.join() 
                        break
                    if self.processes['6'] == 0:
                        proc = 6 
                        p6 = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.run(proc))
                        p6.start()
                        p6.join() 
                        break 


    def run(self, process):
            while True:
                if self.processes['1'] == 0:
                    self.processes['1'] = process
                    self.text.delete('1.0', END)
                    me = 1
                    break
                if self.processes['2'] == 0:
                    self.processes['2'] = process
                    self.text2.delete('1.0', END)
                    me = 2
                    break
                if self.processes['3'] == 0:
                    self.processes['3'] = process
                    self.text3.delete('1.0', END)
                    me = 3
                    break
                if self.processes['4'] == 0:
                    self.processes['4'] = process
                    self.text4.delete('1.0', END)
                    me = 4
                    break
                if self.processes['5'] == 0:
                    self.processes['5'] = process
                    self.text5.delete('1.0', END)
                    me = 5
                    break
                if self.processes['6'] == 0:
                    self.processes['6'] = process
                    self.text6.delete('1.0', END)
                    me = 6
                    break
                else:
                    return
            time.sleep(2)
            self.text1 = "done 1/10"
            self.update(me)
            time.sleep(5)  
            self.text1 = "done 2/10"
            self.update(me) 
            time.sleep(3)             
            self.text1 = "done 3/10"
            self.update(me)
            time.sleep(8)
            self.text1 = "done 4/10"
            self.update(me)
            time.sleep(2) 
            self.text1 = "done 5/10"
            self.update(me)            
            if me== 1:
                self.processes['1'] = 0
            if me== 2:
                self.processes['2'] = 0
            if me== 3:
                self.processes['3'] = 0            
            if me== 4:
                self.processes['4'] = 0
            if me== 5:
                self.processes['5'] = 0
            if me== 6:
                self.processes['6'] = 0  

if __name__ == '__main__':     
    master = tk.Tk()
    ma = main(master)
    master.mainloop()
```

I'm new to multiprocessing so if you have any good advice for me on how to do it right I would be really thankful.

Comment: Read about [multiprocessing.Process.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.join), **it's a blocking function**.

Comment: So join blocks the calling thread until the process whose join() method is called terminates or until the optional timeout occurs. right? but thats not the problem. I might have forgot to add that the 'go' function is called in an extra thread in the real program and not through a button click. Or have i missunderstood sth. The Programm is running fine, but adding processes slows the already existing down

Comment: As it stands, there are the following errors: **1.**: `...(target=self.run(proc)` does not start `.run(proc)` in a `Process`. **2.**: `break`, breaks your `while True:`. Therefore i can't imagin that any further item from `self.processes` are processed. **3.** `self.threads` is undefined. Read about [mcve] and read the [examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#examples) to see how to do - **scroll down your Issue is in the last block**.

Comment: @stovfl sry you are right i have changed it. I hope its more understandable now

Comment: ***"have changed it"***: Far away from [mcve]. Removes only **3.**.

Comment: @stovfl to **1** how do i call it correct then? if i use `multiprocessing.Process(target=self.run, args=(proc,))`  im getting `ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: can't pickle _tkinter.tkapp objects`

Comment: Read [how-can-i-send-python-multiprocessing-process-output-to-a-tkinter-gui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227808/how-can-i-send-python-multiprocessing-process-output-to-a-tkinter-gui) to get a starting point.